# Two independent Oracle Views run fast but are extremely slow when combined

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, select, view

I have two separate views that return data in Oracle.  Queries using the views independently work well but a query using both views together is extremely slow.  Here is an example:

```
create view masterview as 
select masterno,detailno from mastertable;

create view detailview as 
select detailno,field1,field2 from detailtable;
```

MasterTable has an index on MasterNo and DetailTable has an index on DetailNo.

```
select * from masterview 
where masterno = 1234; -- 0.429 seconds to run

select * from detailview 
where detailno in (10,20,30); -- 0.251 seconds to run

select * from DetailView 
where DetailNo in (Select DetailNo from MasterView 
                   where MasterNo = 1234); -- 407.057 seconds to run
```

I have tried using a number of approaches but none have made a difference.  How can I get the combined query to run fast?

The problem appears to be related to the view.  I can eliminate the second view and I can eliminate the IN and the problem persists:

```
select d.*
  from detailview d, testtable t
 where t.masterno = 1234
   and d.detailno = t.detailno;
-- DetailTable used by DetailView is indexed on DetailNo.
-- TestTable is indexed on MasterNo
-- TestTable contains two fields MasterNo,DetailNo
-- This takes 100's of seconds to run

select d.*
  from detailtable d, testtable t
 where t.masterno = 1234
   and d.detailno = t.detailno;
-- This runs in less than a second.
```

Comment: i guess oracle dont use your index. oracle has a complex algorithm to decide if a index should be used. You can use EXPLAIN [Query] to get more information how your query is processed.

Comment: Which version of Oracle? Also, please post the output from EXPLAIN PLAN runs for each query.

Comment: And the first query returns `(10,20,30)`?

Comment: As already mentioned it is difficult to provide any help without an execution plan, design, amount of data, etc. Anyway, you may try the [NO_MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABCGJDI) hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN`. Maybe, Your query performance slow due to `IN`

```
select d.* 
from DetailView as d
inner join MasterView  as m 
  on d.DetailNo = m.DetailNo AND  m.MasterNo = 1234;
```

Comment: I would not bet on this in the case of Oracle. Moreover, it is not an equivalent query.

Comment: @RadimBača - restricting the projection to the columns of `DetailView` does make the two queries return equivalent result sets. Although I agree that in the absence of hard facts - data volumes and distribution, explain plans, etc - any proposed solution is just a guess.

Comment: I suspected the IN and had tried several other approaches and still had the performance problem. I also eliminated the second view and the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try this:

```
select d.* 
  from MasterView m, DetailView d
 where m.MasterNo = 1234
   and m.DetailNo = d.DetailNo
;
```

if DetailNo in mastertable non unique, use distinct

```
select distinct d.* ...
```